# Is it possible to use React's context without PropTypes?

Tags: reactjs

A project I'm working on recently moved to TypeScript, rendering React's PropTypes superfluous, except for specifying `contextTypes`. Now we're in the process of upgrading to a React version past 15.5, where PropTypes were moved to a separate package than `react`. Since our use of PropTypes is so limited, it seems unnecessary to add the `prop-types` dependency if there is a way to use React's context without them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just having the key on the `contextTypes` object seems to work fine (assuming it uses [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) under the hood), but for it to not log any errors, a function that returns `null` seems to be necessary. This works for both `contextTypes` as well as `childContextTypes`.

```
static contextTypes = {
  router: () => null
};

static childContextTypes = {
  location: () => null
};

getChildContext() {
  return { location: this.props.location };
}
```

In some instances, TypeScript complains that `() => null` doesn't have a property `isRequired`. I solved this by creating the helper function `fakePropType`:

```
const fakePropType: any = () => null
fakeProptype.isRequired = () => null
```